# Connecting to Cassandra through SoapUI

Tags: cassandra, soapui, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to connect to Cassandra(3.0) database through SOAP UI. Has any one successfully connected through SoapUI. Can you please share the steps? ( I have followed other threads on this topic , but I was not able to connect successfully)

Groovy step

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.*;

com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
def con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://abc:9042/keyspName"); 
 def stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Error Response:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/TFramedTransportFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error at line:

Cassandra Version:
Cassandra 3.0.12.1586 | DSE 5.0.7 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

Answer (score 0):

`jdk / jre 7` is being used at the moment by SoapUI. However, the above error suggests that `jdk / jre 8` needs to be used.

Install the new java version.

Set the same in the following utilities present under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/` directory. Note that back those files before changing them.

- soapui.bat(.sh)
- testrunner.bat(.sh)

And invoke the soapui / testrunner utility from command line (rather than using desktop shortcut icon).

Answer (score 0):

Place following jars in C:>>>SmartBear\SoapUI-XX\lib
[Required drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Q13.png)

For basic connection:

//==================================================//

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

def cluster= Cluster.builder().withCredentials("USER","PASSWORD").addContactPoints("HOSTNAME").build().connect('Schema');

//====================================================//

If it complains about Guava major/minor version,
check for guava version less than 16.0.1 and delete it.